# How to resolve Resource Type does not belong to resourceCostCalculator map error in estimating AWS CloudFormation template cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to figure out the estimated cost of my simple CloudFormation template using CLI. But I am getting the error this error when I execute the command.

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the EstimateTemplateCost operation: Resource Type AWS::SecretsManager::Secret (Logical ID: MyRDSSecret) does not belong to resourceCostCalculator map.
```

This is my template (template.yaml).

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Database using secret manager with rotation"
Resources:
  MyRDSSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: 'ProdDBSecret'
      Description: 'Secret with dynamically generated password.'
      GenerateSecretString:
        RequireEachIncludedType: True
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "MyDBAdmin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: 'password'
        PasswordLength: 25
        ExcludePunctuation: True

  MyRDSInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      Engine: mysql
      MasterUsername: !Join [ '', [ '{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref MyRDSSecret, ':SecretString:username}}' ] ]
      MasterUserPassword: !Join [ '', [ '{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref MyRDSSecret, ':SecretString:password}}' ] ]
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 3
      DBInstanceIdentifier: 'prod-db-with-rotation'

  SecretRDSInstanceAttachment:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment
    Properties:
      SecretId: !Ref MyRDSSecret
      TargetId: !Ref MyRDSInstance
      TargetType: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
```

This is the command I run

```
aws cloudformation estimate-template-cost \
--template-body \
file://template.yaml \
--query Url \
--output text
```

How can I fix the command to support AWS secret manager resources?